# Different side bar Menu for different wordpress Pages

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Is it possible that we can absolutely have different sidebar menus for different pages in wordpress?

say 7 pages have different sidebar menus.
and other 8 pages may have different sidebar menus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are several ways of doing this, but if your theme already has a sidebar setup, you might want to use a plugin like [Dynamic Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-widgets/) to control which pages your widgets should display on. It's pretty intuitive, but always read the FAQ first.

Comment: Thanks, apart from this widget any plugin method so that each page can select, which sidebar menu it can display?

Comment: Personally - if the layout/width/column of all of them are the same and its just the content that is different - I would go with the widget method, otherwise you'd be setting up multiple sidebars in your functions.php. Keep thing simple imho ;)    

If you insist on the multiple sidebars - perhaps do a search in the Plugin Repository for a plugin you have in mind because sadly I do not know of any.